# How to recursively iterate on dictionary and return the result?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to iterate on a python dictionary which may contain another dictionary, list, or string, compare the values with an expected one and return if a match occurs

```py
def recurse(node, finding, round=0):
    print(str(round) + " -> " + str(node))
    if "name" in node:
        if node["name"] == finding:
            print("FOUND!!!")
            return node
    if isinstance(node, list):
        for item in node:
            recurse(item, finding, round+1)
    if isinstance(node, dict):
        for key, value in node.items():
            recurse(value, finding, round+1)


def main():

    fruit = [
        {
            "green": [
                    {"name": "apple"},
                    {"price": "good"},
                    "random string"
                ],
            "red":  [
                    {"name": "strawberry"},
                    "another random string",
                    {"price": "high"}
                ]
        },
        "final random string",
        {
            "yellow": [
                    {"name": "peach"},
                    {"price": "bad at winter"}
                ]
        }
    ]

    print(recurse(fruit, "strawberry"))
    pass

main()
```

The following snippet always return with `None`, even if during the recursion a match occurs.

The output:

```
0 -> [{'green': [{'name': 'apple'}, {'price': 'good'}, 'random string'], 'red': [{'name': 'strawberry'}, 'another random string', {'price': 'high'}]}, 'final random string', {'yellow': [{'name': 'peach'}, {'price': 'bad at winter'}]}]
1 -> {'green': [{'name': 'apple'}, {'price': 'good'}, 'random string'], 'red': [{'name': 'strawberry'}, 'another random string', {'price': 'high'}]}
2 -> [{'name': 'apple'}, {'price': 'good'}, 'random string']
3 -> {'name': 'apple'}
4 -> apple
3 -> {'price': 'good'}
4 -> good
3 -> random string
2 -> [{'name': 'strawberry'}, 'another random string', {'price': 'high'}]
3 -> {'name': 'strawberry'}
FOUND!!!
3 -> another random string
3 -> {'price': 'high'}
4 -> high
1 -> final random string
1 -> {'yellow': [{'name': 'peach'}, {'price': 'bad at winter'}]}
2 -> [{'name': 'peach'}, {'price': 'bad at winter'}]
3 -> {'name': 'peach'}
4 -> peach
3 -> {'price': 'bad at winter'}
4 -> bad at winter
None
```

During a recursion, is it possible to return with the finding and stop the iteration, and if yes, then how?

Expected output: `{"name": "strawberry"}` got `None`.

Note: I also tried to return every recurse call like `return recurse(item, finding, round+1)` at line 9 and 12, in this case, when the function reached the deepest node, it stopped without finding and got the following output:

```
0 -> [{'green': [{'name': 'apple'}, {'price': 'good'}, 'random string'], 'red': [{'name': 'strawberry'}, 'another random string', {'price': 'high'}]}, 'final random string', {'yellow': [{'name': 'peach'}, {'price': 'bad at winter'}]}]
1 -> {'green': [{'name': 'apple'}, {'price': 'good'}, 'random string'], 'red': [{'name': 'strawberry'}, 'another random string', {'price': 'high'}]}
2 -> [{'name': 'apple'}, {'price': 'good'}, 'random string']
3 -> {'name': 'apple'}
4 -> apple
None
```

Comment: A `return` statement in a recursive function only returns *one level*, to the immediate caller of that level of the function.  You need to add a `return` in front of all the recursive calls, to keep passing the found value all the way up to the top level.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @jasonharper I got the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the recursive calls in your loops to save and evaluate the value that gets returned from the recursion. If you get a real value back, you need to return it (stopping the iteration). If you get `None` back, it means the recursive search didn't find the target, so you keep iterating. I'd also suggest adding `return None` at the end of the code, so the failure condition is explicit:

```
def recurse(node, finding, round=0):
    print(str(round) + " -> " + str(node))
    if "name" in node:
        if node["name"] == finding:
            print("FOUND!!!")
            return node
    if isinstance(node, list):
        for item in node:
            result = recurse(item, finding, round+1)
            if result is not None:
                return result
    if isinstance(node, dict):
        for key, value in node.items():
            result = recurse(value, finding, round+1)
            if result is not None:
                return result
    return None  # not strictly necessary
```

Answer (score 1):

As @jasonharper said in a comment, a recursive function will need to return values from calls to itself if it needs to return a result. Here's how to modify your function to do that — and shows how it would be used:

```
def recurse(node, finding, round=0):
    print(str(round) + " -> " + str(node))
    if "name" in node:
        if node["name"] == finding:
            print("  FOUND!!!")
            return node
    if isinstance(node, list):
        for item in node:
            res = recurse(item, finding, round+1)
            if res:
                return res
    if isinstance(node, dict):
        for key, value in node.items():
            res = recurse(value, finding, round+1)
            if res:
                return res


def main():

    fruit = [
        {
            "green": [
                    {"name": "apple"},
                    {"price": "good"},
                    "random string"
                ],
            "red":  [
                    {"name": "strawberry"},
                    "another random string",
                    {"price": "high"}
                ]
        },
        "final random string",
        {
            "yellow": [
                    {"name": "peach"},
                    {"price": "bad at winter"}
                ]
        }
    ]

    target = "strawberry"
    print(f'Searching for {target!r} in fruit')
    res = recurse(fruit, target)
    if res:
        print(f'  Node: {res}')
    else:
        print('NOT FOUND!')

main()
```